# PDO - query not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Having trouble with query results. The `getSales()` function works great the first time it is called. When called again, the query produces no results. Here is a small chunk of code:

```
abstract class Reporting {
        protected function connect() {
            try {
                $this->dbh = PDOConnection::getInstance();

                if (!$this->dbh instanceof PDO) {
                    throw new CustomException('Unable to connect to database');
                }
            }
            catch (CustomException $e) {
                echo $e;
            }
        }
}
class TenMinuteSales extends Reporting {

        protected $date;

        public function __construct($date) {
            $this->date = new DateTime($date);
            $this->date = $this->date->format('Y-m-d');
        }

        public function beginReport() {
            parent::connect();
        }

        public function getSales($meridiem, $date) {
            try {
                $statement = "SELECT directory.location, IFNULL(sales.daily_sales,0.00) AS sales, IFNULL(sales.cover_counts,0) AS covers
                              FROM t_directory directory
                              LEFT JOIN v_sales_all sales
                              ON sales.site_id = directory.site_id
                              AND sales.business_date = :date
                              AND sales.meridiem = :meridiem
                              ORDER BY directory.site_id ASC
                              LIMIT :totalLocations";

                $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($statement);
                $sth->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(':meridiem', $meridiem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sth->bindParam(':totalLocations', $this->totalLocations, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sth->execute();

                switch ($meridiem) {
                    case 'AM': 
                        $this->amSales = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        return $this->amSales;
                    case 'PM':
                        $this->pmSales = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        return $this->pmSales;
                }
            }
            catch (CustomException $e) {
                echo $e;
            }
        }

$tms = new TenMinuteSales($date);
$tms->beginReport();
$amSales = $tms->getSales('AM', $date);
$pmSales = $tms->getSales('PM', $date);
```

When I call `getSales()` for AM or PM sales numbers, the function successfully returns the data. When I call it a second time, the function doesn't return any data. Not sure if I need to free the results or something along those lines. I tried `unset($sth)` and `$sth->closeCursor()`, none of which seems to fix my problem. Any help with fixing my issue would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: As far as I can see, `$this->totalLocations` is not defined, and probably NULL, is that correct?

Comment: I didn't include the code where that is set. For the purpose of this question. `$this->totalLocations` = 20

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you seem to be abusing try/catch. Your catch in getSales() would never happen, because nothing is thrown to that level.

Comment: I'm aware. I just cut and paste some of the relevant code.

Comment: If this is pruned code... A lot can happen... For ease of mind: what happens if you use `bindValue` rather then `bindParam`?

Comment: @Wrikken, using `bindValue` worked! Do you want to answer the question so I can vote you up and give you credit for the answwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not the whole code, it is important to note that `->bindParam` works by *reference* to a variable, which could result in unexpected behavior if you are not paying very close attention to everything that happens to those variables later on. If you don't explicitly need a reference, using `->bindValue` (which, as the name states, binds the variable by value) is safer, easier and most of all much clearer. Apparently this worked here, but exactly *why* is hard to state without complete code ;)

Comment: Thanks again. I can't believe I overlooked the `bindParam`